# Embedding Youtube player on website page

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, embed

Having had some very basic HTML involvement in a previous website I was involved with, I am learning HTML and CSS in an effort to be able to do more work on my new website.

Currently I have a static image of a Youtube video, with a link that opens up a fullscreen player on a new page, but I'd like to replace that static image with an embedded Youtube player to play the video on my webpage.

There are a few places on the webpage (http://www.johnpearsesafaris.com/page-news-ls.html#) this method is used, but I am trying initially to just make the change to the uppermost image of the falcon with wings splayed, under the title 'How Did they ever film this?"

I initially went to the youtube site that explains the various embed player options they have and decided to go with the iframe one, as i have used iframes elsewhere before.

On my first attempt, I managed to get the player to embed itself and the video to play, but unfortunately it screwed up the rest of the formatting on the page. The static images for all the others News posts below it disappeared and the formatting of the rest of the page went out of whack.

=I then looked at a number of different guidelines on how to do it, and have spent a number of hours trying to rectify the situation, but I can't seem to overcome the break in formatting.

What I did was replace the HTML between rows 166 and 185 with the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="loop-posts eight columns">
    <div id="div3" class="post-CLASS blog-post-item b30">
      <div class="post-heading">
        <h2 class="blog-title"><a
     href="https://www.youtube.com/v/XBEyCr5AoIs" target="_blank">How
    did they ever film this?</a> </h2>
        <div class="blog-meta"> <span class="blog-date">FEB
    2014 <span class="blog-author"><span>
    By </span><a class="blog-author-tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="View all posts by TheEditor" href="#">The
    Editor</a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-thumb-wrapper">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XBEyCr5AoIs" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" width="640"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-excerpt">
        <p>How did they ever film this?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping that it's a simple oversight on my part. What is really confusing me is the div classes.

I confess I don't know enough about them but have been watching multiple instructional videos and using various other sources in a desperate effort to get up to speed.

I would really appreciate any help / guidance anyone could give me in helping me resolve the matter. I will continue to try to fix it on my own in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="loop-posts eight columns">
        <div class="post-CLASS blog-post-item b30" id="div3">
            <div class="post-heading">
                <h2 class="blog-title"><a href=
                "https://www.youtube.com/v/XBEyCr5AoIs" target="_blank">How
                did they ever film this?</a></h2>

                <div class="blog-meta">
                    <span class="blog-date">FEB 2014 <span class=
                    "blog-author">By <a class=
                    "blog-author-tooltip" data-original-title=
                    "View all posts by TheEditor" href="#" rel=
                    "tooltip">The Editor</a></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <iframe frameborder="0" height="360" src=
                "//www.youtube.com/embed/XBEyCr5AoIs" width="640"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-excerpt">
                <p>How did they ever film this?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```